# Angular 4: How to download a file from URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to download a file directly to desktop from a given HTTP URL in Angular 4 project?

For example, I have this URL - http://XXXXXX/XXXX/content/XXX/2/5.xml.

And I have used it as below -

```
<a href="http://XXXXXX/XXXX/content/XXX/2/5.xml" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-round btn-just-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Download">
        <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

This opens the contents of the file in a new window. Instead I want it to be downloaded as 5.xml.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal HTML attribute, add `download` to your `a` element

Comment: Right! Works on Chrome. But not on Firefox v58.

Comment: Not sure how, if you take a look here, it should work: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp